# Newbie question here regaring screen resolution

Tags: xorg, display-resolution, chromium, monitor, touchscreen

I have a question where I bet you can help me out.
First of a little of the backstory: I had run a RPi 4 with raspian and a kiosk mode to display my smarthome.

I needed to switch to an Ubuntu build because I wanted to run on this (else overpowered pi) another application called OSKR for my Vector of Anki. But thats another story.

Long story short: I am at this point where everything starts to work. OSKR is working, smart home shows up and the screen goes out after x seconds of no movement and turns back on when it detects some.

But I have a weird issue that I could not resolve. On raspbian this chromium screen was maximized and had no bars at the ends (the resolution of the page is 800*480)

But with ubuntu it looks that way:

[image: Bars and unused space]

You have bars at the right + bottom and a little of unsed space (?) afterwards.
I guess it has something to do with either the chromium or display resolution...

Has anyone an idea on where I can look?
The xrandr command does not help me because the touchscreen is directly attached to the pi and not over hdmi.

Here are some infos:

[image: Specs]

Thank you and kind regards,

Klena ;)

Comment: Look at the time displayed in the top right corner. Or rather, at the big time display. It looks like **as if the background was pulled out from under the elements of the page**. This therefore seems to be a CSS problem. I saw similar background problems where the CSS `flexbox` declarations were not ironed out properly by the developer of the user interface. Is this displaying in Chromium? Who is the developer of this user interface? They should probably be informed about this issue.

Comment: Also, what is up on the left edge of the screen? Stuff is cut out. Is this because you have scrolled sideways?

Comment: The `inxi -b` output would be better if pasted into the text body of your question; would be easier to read. Here is how to format: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19527/1157519

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a theory.

It might be the case that the developer of this user interface has hardcoded the dimensions of page elements in their "stylesheets" (CSS code).

Now, on a different operating system, you have different fonts. The font chosen by Chromium on Ubuntu is somewhat larger than the font on the previous OS, and the one that the developer of this application has seen on their machine.

Therefore the big time display is overflowing the area that was designated to it. That could be causing all these symptoms.

Can you disable displaying the seconds on the big time display? Does it solve the issue with the layout?

Can you configure Chromium to use different fallback fonts (probably in the sans-serif variant)?

By all means, the developer of the user interface should be informed about this.

---

This may or may not work, but worth trying: *zooming out* the view in Chromium might also impact the issue with the too-big text, and therefore the scrollbars. If you had a keyboard attached, that would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. (Some browsers have a customization setting: zoom text only. This would be relevant in this case.)

Comment: It seems you are somehow right. I shrinked the clock and now it fits the screen... Well I guess I need to work with that :)